# ag-grid: Make whole row a grip for row dragging

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, ag-grid

I am using the Vue version of ag-grid 21.2.1 (https://www.ag-grid.com/vue-getting-started/) and implemented Row Dragging (https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-dragging/) on one of our tables. Everything seems to work out fine, but now I want to make the whole row a "grip" for dragging.
I tried with `pointer-events: none` on `.ag-row` and making the native ag grip item bigger and clickable, but this doesn't seem to work:

```
.ag-icon-grip {
    position: absolute;
    width: 600px;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

Did anyone have any success on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be other methods with `javascript` but you can do it with `css` like below

css

```
.drag-row {
    overflow: unset !important;
}
.drag-row .ag-cell-value {
    padding-left: 24px;
}
.drag-row .ag-row-drag {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1200px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

js

```
this.columnDefs = [
  {
    field: "athlete",
    cellClass: 'drag-row',
    rowDrag: true
  },
  // ...
];
```

working plunker https://next.plnkr.co/edit/naFYtZTBZUJJOCfB

Comment: Thank you! In my case this solution did not work out as of yet. but since your plunker works, I guess it's due to our custom styling of ag-grid. I still wanna try to make it work.

Comment: I finally found out why it did not work - the `cellClass: `drag-row` was replaced in my extension of the ag-grid-vue component. Now it works perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Please check this working [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/52Pc0YPKVZCxj9yOlMAI?p=preview)

---

First you need set [`rowDrag`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-dragging/) in `defaultColDef` like below

```js
this.defaultColDef = {
  rowDrag: true,
  width: 150,
  sortable: true,
  filter: true
};
```

And after then you need to apply the CSS for others `ag-icon-grip` opactiy is `0` except first column like below

```css
.ag-icon-grip {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: auto;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
//Setting opacity for first column is 1
.first-drag-column .ag-icon-grip {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

And inside of vue component, Need to add `cellClass` to showing first column drag icon. Like below

```js
this.columnDefs = [
  {field: "athlete",cellClass: 'first-drag-column',},
  { field: "country" },
  { field: "year" },
  { field: "date" },
  { field: "sport" },
  { field: "gold" },
  { field: "silver" },
  { field: "bronze" }
];
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! this would work as well, but I prefer @Ja9ad335h 's answer, since it uses only one DOM element.

Comment: @low_rents yes if you looking for `DOM` level then good, but when you drag a row by selecting any column, so you will always see first column text. But in my solution you will not see only one column name. it will show you the triggered column text.

Comment: yes, that makes sense. but in my case I hide the DnD ghost label either way.